# PHP script needs at least 3x the amount of ram on Kubernetes

Tags: php, docker, kubernetes

I'm running some scheduled commands on Kubernetes using PHP.

When running the command on local docker PHP RAM usage is at least 70% less than on Kubernetes.

I'm using the same Docker Image on both local and Kubernetes.

An example script:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$remotePath = 'https://server/file.csv'; // Around 150MB

function downloadViaCurl($remotePath)
{
    $commandline = sprintf(
        'curl -o %s %s',
        '/tmp/file.csv',
        $remotePath
    );

    $process = new Process($commandline);
    $process->disableOutput();
    $process->setTimeout(null);
    $process->run();
}

downloadViaCurl($remotePath);

$memory = memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1000000;
echo sprintf("Used %.2fMB of RAM" . PHP_EOL, $memory);
```

The output for Local Docker:

> Used 2.10MB of RAM

The output on K8S:

> Used 6.29Mb of RAM

Dockerfile and job.yaml can be found on https://github.com/InFog/memory_issues

Comment: With `memory_get_peak_usage(true)` your script returns **allocated** memory.  Can you set `memory_get_peak_usage(false)` to see if memory **used** returns similar results?

Comment: used memory returns the following:

`Used 4.55MB of RAM`, on **Kubernetes**.
`Used 1.83MB of RAM`, on **Local**.

Comment: Building a docker image from your repo, running and performing a http request results in connection reset by peer

Comment: No HTTP there. You can log into the container and run `php download.php`

Comment: If the problem was a configuration issue, then please delete the question, or self answer your question, but don't edit the starting post

Comment: Sounds good, @Icepickle.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issues.

1 - The K8S deployment was setting the application to development mode. This is a Symfony application using Doctrine ORM. Doctrine ORM's profiling was active, this made it collect all the queries in memory, growing the amount of needed memory a lot. FOr long running processes with up to a million queries it was using around 500MB of RAM and after changing it to not profile it uses less than 30MB.

Lesson learned: Always check the production parameters.

2 - The second problem: For each time the cronjob runs K8S will run a new container with no Symfony cache. This will also impact memory usage. I solved this by warming up Symfony cache before pushing the image to the registry.